# Socket.IO kubernetes

Tags: sockets, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm creating a web application, where I'm using Kubernetes, in my backend application I have a server that listens to socket connections on port 3000, I deployed my application (front and back) and it works fine I can get data by HTTP requests ... now I want to establish a socket connection with my backend application, but I don't know which address and which port  I have to use in my frontend application (or which configuration to do), I searched with my few keywords but I can't find a tutorial or documentation for this if anyone has an idea I would be thankful

Comment: Hi, assuming that you want to connect your `frontend` `Pod` (or better `Deployment`) to your `backend` `Pod` (or better `Deployment`) you should use a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). A `Service` will allow you to expose your sets of Pods as a network service. I'd reckon you can also check this documentation on how you can connect frontend to backend (focus on `Service` part): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/ . Please tell if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Each deployment (frontend and backend) should have its own service.

Ingress (web) traffic would be routed to the frontend service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

In this example, your frontend application would talk to host: `backend-svc` on port `6379` for a backend connection.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

Example API implementation:

```
io.adapter(socketRedis({ host: 'backend-svc', port: '6379' }));
```